# Team Foundation Server 2012 (WorkItem object does not contain „AssignedTo“ property)

Tags: tfs-workitem, wiql

Code snippet:

```
string WIQL = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.AssignedTo] = @Me AND [System.State] <> '400 CLOSED' ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]";

List<WorkItem> w = getWorkItemsAsList(_workItemStore.Query(WIQL));
```

I have found examples of wiql queries that have [Assignet To] in attributes list,

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [Area Path], [Iteration Path], [Priority], [Test Owner], [Assigned To],[System.State], [System.Reason]
FROM WorkItems
WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' and
      [Iteration Path] != '' and
      [Area Path] Under 'MyProject'
```

but each time such wiql query is executed it returns array of WorkItems without desired property. Therefore my original problem remains.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AssignedTo Property is nested inside another property: Fields.  You can key into that fields collection by referenceName (System.AssignedTo, in this case), something like wi.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value where wi is a WorkItem.  You can also use Linq to operate on the entire WorkItemCollection instead of on a single work item, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved this problem long time ago but forgot to mark this question as solved. The main reason for my confusion is that I didn't really spot the Fields property for a while. Once I did, I've realized why there is no documentation about this online. It's so simple, but not intuitive because some of the properties in my query are available outside fields property.